# Node Selenium WebDriver - Target browser must be a string, but is <object>

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, functional-programming, mocha.js

I'm trying to get functional testing working, with node/mocha.

I've installed selenium webdriver:

```
$ npm install selenium-webdriver
```

and mocha

```
$ npm install -g mocha
```

I'm using a local Vagrant box with Selenium running, and can see sessions starting at:

```
http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html
```

When I run tests, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Target browser must be a string, but is <object>; did you forget to call forBrowser()?
```

Here's my full test:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var assert = require('assert');
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder();
driver.forBrowser("chrome");
driver.usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub');
driver.withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome());
driver.build();

test.describe('Google Search', function() {
  this.timeout(25000);
  test.it('should work', function() {
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().build();

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("webdriver");
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
     assertEquals("webdriver - Google Search", title);
    });

    driver.quit();
  });
});
```

Initially the line declaring the driver was all on one line, but I've split it up and added the call to forBrowser() to try and get it working.

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub').withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
```

No joy.

I've had a look around builder.js and it seems the capabilities aren't being set right, but I can't work out how to fix it - Builder.prototype.build gets called twice from the above test some how, the first time it's called capabilities.get(Capability.BROWSER_NAME) returns "chrome" which is great, but the second time it's called, it has null and bails. I can't work it out.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You build a driver twice. Once here:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder();
driver.forBrowser("chrome");
driver.usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub');
driver.withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome());
driver.build();
```

The second time here, on the 2nd line:

```
  test.it('should work', function() {
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().build();
```

This second occurrence is incorrect. In fact, it seems to look like some code that was left over from an earlier version of your code.